# Subquery returns more than 1 row In case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I write the following query. It's showing subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`*`
FROM
    `t1`
WHERE
    `t1`.`id` IN(
        CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN(
        SELECT
            `t2`.`id`
        FROM
            `t2`
    ) ELSE -1
    END
)
```

But if i remove case statement it's working fine. Like this

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`*`
FROM
    `t1`
WHERE
    `t1`.`id` IN (
        SELECT
            `t2`.`id`
        FROM
            `t2`
    )
```

Can someone please help me for understand this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, and an explanation of the intent of the query.

Comment: The CASE expression should return in any of its branches a scalar value and not a dataset.

Comment: Can you please give any idea for write the query with this exact condition?